# Explanation - "it" instead of "this"

Tags: word-choice, it-its-itself

I'm wondering why the word in the last sentence below must be "it" rather than "this":

> And I would immediately say, “Stop talking! You shouldn't speak when
> you're eating! Always remember this. **It** is a golden rule.

Comment: Who said it must be "it" not "this"? I agree that "it" sounds a bit better, but it's not wrong to say "this".

Answer (score 2):

> And I would immediately say, “Stop talking! You shouldn't speak when you're eating! Always remember this. It is a golden rule.

It's all to do with referents:

Always remember this *(referent = "what I have just indicated by speaking".)*

It *(referent = You shouldn't speak when you're eating!)* is a golden rule.

Compare:

A [speaking to B]: "There are two keys in the table. The only key that is important is this. **[A points at the nearest key]** *(referent = the one I have just indicated by pointing.)* It *(referent = the key that is important)* is the key to the safe.

**This** is a demonstrative - This/these must have a referent that is being indicated/mentioned.

Later A takes B to the safe:

A [speaking to B]: "Have you got **it**?" *The referent of **it**, by context, is the key (associated with the safe) although neither person has pointed to, or mentioned, the key, and neither person can see it.*

B: Yes, **it** is in my pocket."

But

A [speaking to B]: "Have you got **this**?"

B: "What?" *(Naturally, B was expecting something to be indicated or mentioned by A. - There is no context.)*

Note that in your original

> And I would immediately say, “Stop talking! You shouldn't speak when you're eating! Always remember this. It is a golden rule."

**this** and **it** are spoken close together in time and "**this**" can be used in place of **it**.

But in my examples there is a distance in time between "**this**" and "**it** "and "**this**" cannot be used. **This** refers to something that is indicated *now*.

Answer (score 1):

> Always remember this. It is a golden rule.

You already used "this", just 6 letters earlier.  To use it a second time makes it sound like you're stuttering.

Answer (score 0):

You can say **this**. The grammar wouldn't be wrong. The term would just be *redundant* and hence in poor form.